# Why do I get this syntax Error in my Kivy app

Tags: kivy

```
<CustButton@Button>:
  font_size:32
<CalcGridLayout>:
  id: calculator
  display:entry
  rows:6
  padding:10
  spacing:10
```

I get this error

```
<CustButton@Button>:
^ Syntax Error:invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please provide code snippet

Comment: It looks like there are some indentation errors. Make sure that the line below has an indentation of at least 4 spaces (or one tab)